# How to replace strings in a file and "save" it as another file

Tags: perl, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace a string in a bunch of *.txt files. I'm familiar with this command:

```
find "$folder" -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i 's/REPLACEFROM/REPLACETO/g' {} \;
```

However, this (as per -i flag) replaces strings inplace.

What I'd like to do is keep all original files intact and "save" the changed files as "file1-renamed.txt", "file2-renamed.txt", ...

What's the fastest and most elegant way to do that? Maybe perl?

I'm sure this is pretty basic, but it seems to hard for me. :)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

With sed, you can use

```
 sed -i.back
```

this way, original file will be moved to *.back

Or use this snippet to be closest as your question :

```
find "$folder" -type f -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c '
    cp "$1" "${1%.*}-renamed.txt"
    sed -i 's/REPLACEFROM/REPLACETO/g' "${1%.*}-renamed.txt"
' -- {} \;
```

Comment: Perl also has an `-i` switch which works the same way: `-i.bak` will cause the original file to be saved with `.bak` appended to the filename.

Answer (score 2):

With perl you may try something like this:

```
find "$folder" -name '*.txt' |
  xargs perl -ne 'open NEW, ">>$ARGV.new"; s/from/to/g; print NEW'
```

This would save new files as old-name.txt.new. You may need to change it if you really want "old-name-renamed.txt" format. Also note, that it would append to the new files after every execution of the oneliner.

Of course, it would be easier to use -i option (`... perl -i.old -pe 's/from/to/g'`) and then bulk-rename files to desirable name format, so this solution is probably make sense only if original files are not accessible for writing.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

```
find "$folder" -type f -name '*.txt' |
parallel sed 's/REPLACEFROM/REPLACETO/g' ">" {.}-renamed.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly a one-liner, but it should to the trick (and IMO it's easier to read):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(@ARGV)
{
  my $file=shift;
  open(my $read,"<",$file) or die $!;
  my $output_file=$file . "_renamed";
  if($file=~/^(.+)\.txt$/)
  {
    $output_file=$1 . "-renamed.txt";
  }

  open(my $write,">",$output_file) or die $!;

  while(<$read>)
  {
    chomp;
    s/REPLACEFROM/REPLACETO/g;
    print $write "$_\n";
  }
  close($read);
  close($write);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9235033/786948) here, but another solution crossed my mind today:

```
for f in (find "$folder" -name '*.txt'); do perl -ne 's/from/to/g' $f > "$f.new"; done
```

Again, it will save modified content to "old-name.txt.new" (you may change it to something like `... > "$(basename $f)-renamed.txt" ...` if you want).

This answer is better then my previous one, because it doesn't require opening of the same file for an every new line.